# Why does this code throw an IndexError?

Tags: python, indexing

I am trying to read values from a file, data.txt, with this code. However, it throws an IndexError when I run it. Why would this be happening?

```
def main():

    myfile=open('data.txt','r')
    line=myfile.readline()
    while line!='':
        line=line.split()
        age=line[1]


        line=myfile.readline()
    myfile.close()    
main()
```

Comment: Lists start at index 0.

Comment: Can you share some sample data from `data.txt`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you please give us the contents of data.txt? and what you're expecting to be line[1]?

Comment: You should really use a debugger in situations like this to determine what is happening. While I cannot actually reproduce your exact issue, I know that you would be able to find out the problem by seeing what `line` is before the `age=line[1]` line is executed in order to determine what the problem is. Most likely you're reading a line from your file which only has one word in it, and thus when you call `line.split()`, the array only has one index (starting at index 0), and so attempting to index position 1 causes the IndexError.

Answer (score 2):

If `line` happens to contain exactly one fragment, `line.split()` returns a list of exactly one element, and accessing its second element (at index `1`) leads to an error.

Also, to make your code better, don't ever reassign the variables. It hampers readers, and the code is written mostly to be read, especially by yourself.

I'd use a simpler loop:

```
for line in myfile:  # this iterates over the lines of the file
  fragments = line.split()
  if len(fragments) >= 2:
    age = fragments[1]
    ...
```

Also, the idiomatic way to open the file for a particular duration and close it automatically is the use of `with`:

```
with open(...) as myfile:
  for line in myfile:
     ...
# At this point, the file will be automatically closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    myfile=open('data.txt','r')
    line=myfile.readline()
    while line!='':
        line=line.split()
        try:
            age=line[1]
        except IndexError:
            age = None
        line=myfile.readline()
    myfile.close()    
main()
```

The try statement works as follows.

First, the try clause (the statement(s) between the try and except keywords) is executed.
If no exception occurs, the except clause is skipped and execution of the try statement is finished.
If an exception occurs during execution of the try clause, the rest of the clause is skipped. Then if its type matches the exception named after the except keyword, the except clause is executed, and then execution continues after the try statement.
If an exception occurs which does not match the exception named in the except clause, it is passed on to outer try statements; if no handler is found, it is an unhandled exception and execution stops with a message.

For more details, see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: what does try: does? this code worked thanks.but want to know what is it that try: code does

Answer (score 0):

Python starts indexing at 0.
in your `age=line[1]` part, if there is only one word in the line, Python will throw an `IndexError` to tell you that. Seeing your data would be helpful, but the following is the generally accepted and much easier way of reading  a file:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        # '' is a a false value, so, this is the same as if line != ''
        if line:
            line = line.split()
            # if age is always the first thing on the line:
            age = line[0]
            # if age can be somewhere else on the line, you need to do something more complicated
```

Note that, because you used `with`, you don't need to close the file yourself, the `with` statement does that